# How to use javascript/jquery to loop through table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I have a block of code like below

```
<tbody class="society_list">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Dummy</td>
        <td>Dummy</td>
        <td id="lol0">UPDATE THIS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        .....
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I want to do is to loop through the whole table, find the td with an id, get the value of that id, and then update the html inside.
What I have for now(Sorry I'm quite new and I still don't have much idea what to do...)

```
function update(){
  var trs = document.querySelectorAll('.society_list tr');
  for(i=0;i<trs.length-1;i++){
    trs[i].find('td').each(function(){
      //I know I need to do something here but what's that.. 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: If you know the id of the target element then there is no need to loop, you could just use the id selector to get the element then update the content

Comment: @ArunPJohny Hmm.. Since the id is actually set using another javascript, so I don't quite know what the id is. What I wanna do is to loop through the tds and find one with an id, get the id value and use it to do something..

Comment: then you can use the has attribute selector like `$('.society_list td[id]')` will return all `td` with id attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate through tds which have id attribute using the [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

```
$('.society_list tr td[id]').each(function(){
  var tdID = $(this).attr('id'); // <--- getting the ID here
  var result = doSomeMagicWithId(tdID); // <--- doing something
  $(this).html(result);  // <---- updating the HTML inside the td
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `id` attribute, you don't need to loop through table. With jQuery it's so simple:

```
$('#lol0').text('What you want');
```

OR:

```
$('#lol0').html('What you want');
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/yy4v807L/)

Comment: The OP uses lol0 as one example. I suppose there are lol1, lol2, ... to follow. Maybe .each() is needed?

Comment: And it was clarified in comments, so the @downvote is not fair :(

Answer (score 1):

mate try use

```
$('#tblOne > tbody  > tr').each(function() {...code...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plain JavaScript version:

```
   var os=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i=0;i<os.length;i++){
      var o=os[i];
      if (o.id){
        o.innerHTML="updated "+o.id;
      }
    }
```

I'm tired of the argument that jQuery is really simple. Well under the hood it still has to match all the DOM elements. Some form of iteration still takes place. The plain JavaScript version isn't so bad and it doesn't HIDE complexity. And it runs in all browsers, including the IE versions that the jQuery folks deem "irrelevant".

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addRow(tableID,index) 
{
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;    
    
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

 row.style.backgroundColor = "#FEF0FF";
 rowCount = rowCount-1;

 

 //row.id = "tr_add"+rowCount;
 var cell1   = row.insertCell(0);
 cell1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 cell1.style.align ="center";
 var element1  = document.createElement("input");
 element1.id   = "chk"+(rowCount);
 element1.name   = "chk"+(rowCount);
 element1.type  = "checkbox";
 //element1.style.textAlign="center";
 var element111  = document.createElement("input");
 element111.id   = "chkbox"+(rowCount);
 element111.name = "chkbox"+(rowCount);
 element111.type = "hidden";
    
    var element112  = document.createElement("input");
 element112.id   = "textCopy"+(rowCount);
 element112.name = "textCopy"+(rowCount);
 element112.type = "hidden";
 element112.value ="COPY";
 //cell1.innerHTML = "COPY";
    
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
    cell1.appendChild(element111);
    cell1.appendChild(element112);
    cell1.style.textAlign="center";
    }
```

```js
function addRow(tableID,index) 
{
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;    
    
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

 row.style.backgroundColor = "#FEF0FF";
 rowCount = rowCount-1;

 

 //row.id = "tr_add"+rowCount;
 var cell1   = row.insertCell(0);
 //cell1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 //cell1.style.align ="center";
 var element1  = document.createElement("input");
 element1.id   = "chk"+(rowCount);
 element1.name   = "chk"+(rowCount);
 element1.type  = "checkbox";
 //element1.style.textAlign="center";
 var element111  = document.createElement("input");
 element111.id   = "chkbox"+(rowCount);
 element111.name = "chkbox"+(rowCount);
 element111.type = "hidden";
    
    var element112  = document.createElement("input");
 element112.id   = "textCopy"+(rowCount);
 element112.name = "textCopy"+(rowCount);
 element112.type = "hidden";
 element112.value ="COPY";
 //cell1.innerHTML = "COPY";
    
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
    cell1.appendChild(element111);
    cell1.appendChild(element112);
    cell1.style.textAlign="center";
  
  document.getElementById('hdRowCount').value = rowCount+1;
    document.getElementById('btnCopy'+rowCount).onclick = function(){addRow('tableToModify',rowCount);}; 
  
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <button type="button" name="btnCopy<%=i%>" id="btnCopy<%=i%>" value="Copy" onclick="addRow('tableToModify','<%=i%>');">Copy</button>  
    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```